# Iphone overrides my css properties for the html

Tags: html, css, iphone, bootstrap-5

Ok so I have these properties in css overriding the html for a scroll-snap navigation and in Iphone it simply dissapears and It doesn't scroll at all. Here is my code:
CSS

```
html{
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
  scroll-padding: none;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I do have in the html code this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

I don't understand why on windows and android works perfect but on Iphone it just doesn`t do anything.Just in case it matters I'm using bootstrap 5 for responsiveness. Any solutions?